# Trying to to replace Root expressions from the output of Eigenvalues by the explicit forms

Tags: equation-solving, eigenvalues

When I calculate the eigenvalues of the following matrix (`H`) by using [`Eigenvalues`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eigenvalues.html), I get complex expressions with [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) values. How do I find the explicit eigenvalues with the following assumptions

```
{{J, B, α} ∈ Reals, J > 0, B >= 0,  0 <= α <= π}
```

My Matrix is

```
H = {{2 (J + B Cos[α]), B Sin[α], B Sin[α], 0},
     {B Sin[α], -2 J, 0, B Sin[α]}, 
     {B Sin[α],0, -2 J, B Sin[α]},
     {0, B Sin[α], B Sin[α], 2 (J - B Cos[α])}};
```

[image]

Comment: You could try `ToRadicals`.

Comment: It works, but what about the assumptions?

Comment: `Eigenvalues[H, Cubics -> True]` gives the same result as `Eigenvalues[H] // ToRadicals`

Answer (score 2):

As @b.gates.you.know.what mentions, you can use [`ToRadicals`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToRadicals.html)

```
Eigenvalues[H] // ToRadicals
```

but the resultant expression is not so easy to handle. Even after trying to simplify it under the condition you offer, it helps little:
[image]

Comment: I think that this command did not take my assumptions into account, otherwise why the imaginary part appeared?

Comment: Real roots of cubic equations generally involve imaginary numbers when expressed using radicals. One advantage of `Root` is that you avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

A few comments that may help:

(1)  Since J > 0, factor it out of the matrix (`h1 = H /. J->1`).  B and the eigenvalues of `h` will be in units of J.

(2)  Instead of considering B and $\alpha$ to be the independent variables, define $B_x$ and $B_y$.  (`h2 = H /. J -> 1 /. Cos[α] -> Bx/B /. Sin[α] -> By/B`)

(3)  Another potential set of real, independent variables is `{B^2, B^2*Cos[2α]`.  Look at the `ToRadicals` form of the eigenvalues to find other potential parameters. We know the eigenvalues are real, but choosing real parameters that allow MMA to simplify the imaginary parts to zero is not easy.

(4)  Use `Manipulate` and `Plot` to visualize the eigenvalues as roots of the characteristic polynomial.

```
c1 = CharacteristicPolynomial[h1, x]
Manipulate[Plot[c1 /. B -> sb /. α -> sa, {x, -10, 10},
  PlotRange -> {All, {-100, 100}}],
 {{sb, 1, "B"}, 0, 5}, {{sa, π/4, "α"}, 0, π}]

c2 = CharacteristicPolynomial[h2, x]
Manipulate[Plot[c2 /. Bx -> sbx /. By -> sby, {x, -10, 10},
  PlotRange -> {All, {-100, 100}}],
{{sbx, 1, "Bx"}, 0, 5}, {{sby, 1, "By"}, 0, 5}]
```